# Multiple calls to botocore.stub.Stubber causes exception

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-kms

I am using botocore.stub.Stubber to mock the kmsclient. The code I am using is

```
with botocore.stub.Stubber(s3) as stubber:
        with botocore.stub.Stubber(kms) as stubber2:
            stubber.add_response('copy_object', response, expectedParams)
            stubber.activate()
            stubber2.add_response('decrypt', response2, expectedParams2)
            stubber2.activate()
            handleCore(__makeValidEvent(), None, s3, kms)
            stubber.assert_no_pending_responses()
            stubber2.assert_no_pending_responses()
```

With the actual implementation the kmsclient call is happening twice which results in the following exception

```
params = {'CiphertextBlob': b"\x01\x02\x02\x00x#\xc1\xdbp6\xe1Y\x0fS\x15\x80<\x86\xb5\xb2\x86\x9f\xaf\xa2Z\x07\xfef\x8d\xb2\xd7...\t'\xe2\xb9\x10w0\x83\xcb\xe1\xcb`\xd1\xc2\x8c\xe4\x82Q/*\xb3]\xcfZ\xb9\xbd\x1c\x9c\x96(e\x94j\x1a\x91\xba\xaeO[>\x97"}

    def _assert_expected_call_order(self, model, params):
        if not self._queue:
            raise UnStubbedResponseError(
                operation_name=model.name,
                reason=(
>                       'Unexpected API Call: A call was made but no additional calls expected.'
                        'Either the API Call was not stubbed or it was called multiple times.'
                        )
            )
E           botocore.exceptions.UnStubbedResponseError: Error getting response stub for operation Decrypt: Unexpected API Call: A call was made but no additional calls expected.Either the API Call was not stubbed or it was called multiple times.
```

Can someone let me know how can could be used for multiple calls on the same object(kmsclient in this case)

Comment: I have found an alternate solution using moto

Comment: from moto import (
    mock_kms,
    mock_s3,
)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding multiple responses for the same method.

Example test code:

```
############## Test Code
client = botocore.session.get_session().create_client("cloudformation", region_name="us-east-1")
stubber = Stubber(client)

# Generate multiple responses to be returned by boto
responses = [
    {
        "StackId": "stack-a",
    },
    {
        "StackId": "stack-b",
    },
    {
        "StackId": "stack-c",
    },
]

# Add each response to stubber for the same method - "update_termination_protection"
for response in responses:
    stubber.add_response(
        "update_termination_protection",
        response,
    )
stubber.activate()
actual = method_to_test(client, data)
stubber.deactivate()
assert actual == True
```

Example method to test:

```
############## Real method
def method_to_test(self, client, data):
    for item in data:
        client.update_termination_protection(
           EnableTerminationProtection=True,
           StackName=item,
        )
    return True
```

This works and throws no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but found I could fix it by calling deactivate() before I set up the stub.

So, your example would be:

```
with botocore.stub.Stubber(s3) as stubber:
        with botocore.stub.Stubber(kms) as stubber2:
            stubber.deactivate()
            stubber.add_response('copy_object', response, expectedParams)
            stubber.activate()
            stubber2.deactivate()
            stubber2.add_response('decrypt', response2, expectedParams2)
            stubber2.activate()
            handleCore(__makeValidEvent(), None, s3, kms)
            stubber.assert_no_pending_responses()
            stubber2.assert_no_pending_responses()
```

Comment: I know your answer is copying the layout of op's example code for simplicity, but the calls to .deactivate() and .activate() can be avoided by moving the .add_response() calls before the with statements.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Stubber.add_response() documentation](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html#botocore.stub.Stubber.add_response):

> Adds a service response to the response queue.

So if you expect multiple calls to a stubbed method then your test should invoke add_response() multiple times, each with the response and expected params in the order they should be consumed.

So your test code with two calls to kms.decrypt would be arranged like the following:

```py
stubber.add_response('copy_object', response, expectedParams)
stubber2.add_response('decrypt', response2, expectedParams2)
stubber2.add_response('decrypt', response2, expectedParams2)
with botocore.stub.Stubber(s3) as stubber:
        with botocore.stub.Stubber(kms) as stubber2:
            handleCore(__makeValidEvent(), None, s3, kms)
            stubber.assert_no_pending_responses()
            stubber2.assert_no_pending_responses()
```

You may wind up using response2, expectedParams2 and response3, expectedParams3 though if the first and second calls to kms.decrypt are doing different things.

Comment: How is python able resolve the name `stubber` outside of the `with` statement?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when suppose there are multiple API calls for a particular function but there are not sufficient stubbing's to return the response. One must remember two things while stubbing responses

1. Stubbing should be in the same order the API calls are being made.
2. Stubbing must be done as many times as the number of times API call is done.